# defining a button in another class

Tags: java, android

I have 2 java files in my Android project. First is MainActivity and second is Player class. I want to trigger btnPlay events that's defined in MainActivity.java on Player.java. I tried to redefine the button in Player class but that gave me `java.lang.NullPointerException` error when I use `btn.setText("Stop");` in Player class:

```
public class Player extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    Button btnPlay;
    static MediaPlayer mediaplayer;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    }
```

I'm complately out of ideas. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show more code. for example, unless btn.setText("Stop"); is a typo and is really btnPlay.setText("Stop"); we don't see where btn comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think your btnPlay is instantiating twice by the same integer id R.id.btnPlay.
You can give another integer id to this class as R.id.btnPlay1.

And then you can use btnPlay in this class as well.
Or You can use the button defined in MainActivity as:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); //we inflate the layout here
    MainActivity.btn.setText("stop");

}
```

Comment: It wants btnPlay to be static. I make it static and I hope that won't cause it any more troubles. It works now :)